# google maps v3 "dragend"-Event on mobile

Tags: android, iphone, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps v3 "dragend"-Event and it works fine on google chrome on desktop.
But it does not work on a mobile device (iphone/android).

Has anyone else this problem/solved it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, try this on your mobile devices: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html

Comment: Thanks, for the link. It works on mobile. 
More precisely I use the gwt mapper [gwt-google-maps-v3](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3). 
I think now there's something wrong with this mapper. Strange, that it works in chrome on desktop but not on mobile.

Comment: I just tried this link on another Android (4.0) device and it worked like a charm. It _might_ be an issue specific to GWT, just try to see if you can make a very simple map (with and without GWT) to find out.